# Screensharing only one workspace in Qtile

Tags: linux, window-managers, screensharing

I am using qtile as my window manager. I sometimes have to share screen in Google meet to my colleagues. And in order to show all the dropdown menus I am clicking on during the meet have to be screen shared.

Hence I opt for sharing the whole screen and not just only the window.
But sometimes I just to move to another workspace and text someone quickly on Whatsapp or Telegram and get back. This is also visible, since I am sharing the whole screen

Is it possible to share only one workspace at a time and not all workspaces?

Comment: you could start another X session

Comment: I didnt get you, start another X session during a Gmeet ? Could you please elaborate...

Comment: oh, you could start a second X session and start your private windows in it, which probably won't be available to the instance of gmeet running in the first session